# What type of capacitor to buy

Tags: capacitor

[image]What should I look for in a replacement capacitor

Comment: Hi, welcome to EESE. Thank you for providing such a clear high quality picture. It may be possible that someone can answer based only on the picture you have provided. But if you are able, please edit your question to include additional information such as where you found the capacitor (what kind of equipment or motor or whatever did it come from?) and, if you know, what is the purpose of the capacitor in that piece of equipment. This may help you get a better answer.

Comment: What equipment was this used in?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common Motor-Run cap  worth about $10~$15 or more for higher voltage ratings.

Search **22.5uF metallized polypropylene radial capacitor** 250Vac (min)   5%

e.g. M72A2822N22 AEROVOX  280Vac 5%

or another
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/EZP-Q38226MTA/?qs=TiOZkKH1s2QJT3hK7a6J8Q%3D%3D

You can solder to wire leads and silicone or PU adhesive to secure.

Answer (score 0):

I assume its from a bike, but you don't want to go to the official parts dealer?

If you just type 'Ducati Capacitor' into google you get a bunch that look similar for not too much money. See if there is a Ducati part number in there, that should be all you need for a replacement part.

If you are looking for anything else you're taking a chance with a nice machine.

Important numbers:
capacitance: 22,5 uF +/- 5%
voltage: 250 VAC 60Hz

something specifying power or current capability, or impedance

you probably also want a matching 10000h rating (lifetime?)

NOt sure what the -25/85/21 is. At first I thought it was temperature range but some other ones have a group of numbers like that that do not seem like temperatures to me.

the other VERY important thing is the "type" or dielectric material class of the capacitor. If you can get a ducati part#, perhaps you can figure this out from whatever catalog lists it.

Comment: -25 ~ 85'C rated